# What is Serverless Database Capacity in PostgreSQL AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is Serverless Database Capacity in PostgreSQL AWS Cloudwatch ? How it works please explain.

Comment: Generally speaking, this type of question is more suitable in communities like Reddit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServerlessDatabaseCapacity` metric appears to apply to **Amazon Aurora Serverless**, indicating the number of  Aurora Capacity Units (ACUs) being consumed.

At the moment, **only MySQL is available** for Amazon Aurora Serverless. PostgreSQL is not available for Amazon Aurora Serverless. Thus, the metric is not relevant for PostgreSQL.

Comment: This metric is available for PostgreSQL now as well.